# Is G(4,7) a Coxeter group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Let $G(4, 7)$ be an abstract group with the presentation
$$\langle a,b,c | a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1, (ab)^4 = (bc)^4 = (ca)^4 = 1, (acbc)^7 = (baca)^7 = (cbab)^7 = 1 \rangle $$
[Richard Schwartz](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-002-0245-8) considered a representation of $G(4,7)$ into $PU(2,1)$ and extensively studied the image group denoted $\Gamma(4,7)$, for instance, the topology of the complex hyperbolic surface $H^{2}_{\mathbb{C}}/\Gamma(4, 7)$. But I'm more curious about $G(4,7)$ itself.

> Is $G(4,7)$ a Coxeter group?

> Whether $G(4,7)$ is a torsion group in which every element has finite order?

*Edit*: The second question has been answered in negative thanks to comments from Tom and Derek.
I'd like to offer further context regarding the first question. Some topologists including me are interested in the end behavior of $G(4,7)$, for instance, is its boundary a Menger curve? Note that Jordane Granier in 2015 dissertation considered a similar group
$$\langle \iota_1,\dots, \iota_6|\iota_{i}^{3} = id, \iota_{i}\iota_{i+1} = \iota_{i+1}\iota_{i}, i\in \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \rangle$$
It has been shown that this is a hyperbolic group with a Menger curve boundary. This was proved using the classic characterization of hyperbolic group boundaries by [Kapovich-Kleiner](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_2000_4_33_5_647_0.pdf). A pivotal aspect of Granier's proof involved geometrizing the group with the aid of [Dymara-Osajda's](https://eudml.org/doc/282878) building blocks.  Given that
$G(4,7)$ is hyperbolic, it seem natural to turn to Kapovich-Kleiner's characterization. Yet, an appropriate geometrization is necessary. This leads us to the first question, which, if answered affirmatively, would simplify the task. We do suspect it cannot be true, however, so far we don't know how to disprove it.

Comment: About the second question: the elements $a$, $b$ and $c$ are involutions, so surely the group has torsion. Did you perhaps intend to ask whether the group *is* torsion, in the sense that every element has finite order?

Comment: @TomDeMedts Note, however, that the fact that $a$, $b$, and $c$ have order $2$ requires some (easy) justification beyond reading the relators (they could, in principle, all have order $1$!). But the torsion point still stands of course as the trivial group is and has torsion. Also, the existence of finitely presented torsion groups is a famous open problem, and this is definitely not such a group.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Sure, I did the justification in my head before posting my comment ;-) It's easy enough: if $a=1$, then $(cbc)^7=1$ implies $b^7=1$ so also $b=1$, and then also $c=1$, so everything would collapse. But it can't, because the abelianization of the group is non-trivial (it has order $2$).

Comment: Interestingly, this group seems to have $\mathop{\rm PSL}(2,71)$ and $\mathop{\rm PGL}(2,7)$ as quotients.

Comment: The matrices in $\mathop{\rm PSL}(2,71)$ for $a$, $b$, $c$ are $(0 & 1 \\ 70 & 0)$, $(13 & 18 \\ 30 & 58)$ and $(61 & 13 \\ 25 & 10)$.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Yes, thanks. I'll make the change.

Comment: The paper you are referring to contains the statement that $\Gamma(4,7)$ contains a (non-trivial) finite index torsion-free subgroup, so this provides a negative answer to your second question. I strongly suspect that the answer to the first question is also negative.

Comment: More finite quotients include $\mathop{\rm PSL}(3,8)$, $\mathop{\rm PSL}(3,13)$, $\mathop{\rm PSL}(3,29)$, $\mathop{\rm PSU}(3,27)$.

Comment: An easy computation shows that there is a subgroup of index $8$ with infinite abelianization, so it is certainly not a torsion group. It seems unlikely that it is a Coxeter group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Presumably this is the point stabiliser for the homomorphism to $\mathrm{PGL}(2,7)$.

Comment: @DaveBenson Yes that's right. It's the only subgroup of index $8$ up to conjugacy.

Comment: @ShijieGu I agree with Derek Holt that it seems unlikely that this is a Coxeter group.  Do you have some reason to hope/suspect that it is?  Or some idea what the simple reflections would be?

Comment: @NathanReading I have the same feeling that this might not be a Coxeter group. Just lacking some tools to disprove it...

Comment: How do you know that your group is hyperbolic?

Comment: @MoisheKohan It's not trivial. One method employed by my friend Jiming Ma involved setting $s_1 = ab$, $s_2 = bc$, and $s_3 = ca$. The resulting presentation denoted $S(4,7)$ is a subgroup of $G(4,7)$ with index 2.  Upon computation, either done manually (as Jiming initially did) or through Magma $S(4,7)$ is hyperbolic. Alternatively, Derek Holt wrote a program in GAP. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238740/verify-that-a-group-is-hyperbolic-via-computer-algebra. Derek's program can be used directly to confirm that $G(4,7)$ is hyperbolic.

Comment: Do you have any information about the center of your group ? Since the abelianization is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, if it is a Coxeter group it must be irreducible, hence have trivial center since it is infinite. So if you find a nontrivial central element, you're done...

Comment: @ThomasGobet The center is finite since it's a hyperbolic group. But we don't know if it's actually centerless.